# An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

We're getting the following error.

> An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters. This exception was caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.

I've read that this issue is normally caused by an issue with the CF mailer. But we are sent any errors that happen on our system, so doubtful it's that. Here is the flow (from what I've found)

1. Use cfpop to login to gmail and get emails.
2. Send mail (using cfmail) to me with a dump of the previous cfpop call (Part of another problem, so to debug I'm emailing myself what CF gets back from the cfpop call).
3. Error happens and is caught.
4. Coldfusion sends me this error in a email, using cfmail.

Do note I thought that there might be too many emails for CF to download them all, so I tried getting less mails to no avail. All cfmail calls use the same details (server, username, password). Also I've tested this on another server (multiple) and it worked then with no issue.

Does anybody have any idea? Anything?

Here is the code in the cfpop. Do note that I have called the underlying Java code to get this working over SSL.

```
<CFPOP ACTION="GetAll" NAME="popHeader"
     SERVER="#Application.emailServer#"
     PORT="995"
     USERNAME="#Application.emailUsername#"
     PASSWORD="#Application.emailPassword#"
     ATTACHMENTPATH="#expandPath('./files/')#"
     GENERATEUNIQUEFILENAMES="YES"/>
```

Comment: is this coming from your cfpop call to gmail? are the emails you're sending go through gmail or a different mail server? does it work ever or is it an intermittent error?

Comment: No it seems to be coming from when I try email myself. The problem is constant, I've tried at different times of the day. Never works.

Comment: In other words, if you forget the cfpop for a moment and you run a page with nothing but a cfmail tag, you get the error?

Comment: And what does your `cfpop` tag look like? Have you verified that you can connect from the ColdFusion server hardware to the server and port listed in your `cfpop` tag? I would try testing to make sure you can make a connection from that server using telnet so you can rule our your network as the issue.

Comment: I've added the cfpop tag. I'm sure that the server can connect to the mail server, as stated in my question. I get a mail with the error in it, from the same server and email account.

Comment: I'm confused. You state that this should be working because you are receiving email from the ColdFusion server.  Your ColdFusion server is using the mail server that you have configured for it under the Mail Server Settings in the admin or within your `cfmail` tag.  Surely that is not a Gmail server, right?  Your `cfpop` tag is attempting to connect to your Gmail account and failing.  This is why we are asking to confirm you can connect from the ColdFusion server to the Gmail server/port you listed.  You are dealing with two different mail servers here (I assume).  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's very confusing I know. So the cfpop tag runs and fails, then we have a global error handler that sends us an email with the error I listed in it. Yes this is a GMail account, no we are not using 2 mail servers. Both emails originate from the same server which uses only 1 email account.